# Printing or Echo form data to csv file

Tags: php, csv

I have listened to a youtube tutorial severally in order to write a php code for online form data and print to CSV file on my website. The code the teacher used on the tutorial works perfectly on my local computer but doesn’t print anything on the CSV file as I have now uploaded the page on my website.

when site users fill the form online and click on submit button on my site – no information from form is printed on the same CSV file. Why?

This is the code I got from the tutorial and wrote the same:

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$names = $_POST['names'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$job = $_POST['job'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$data = $names . "," . $telephone . "," . $email . "," . $job . "," . $city;

$file = "cardealer.csv";

file_put_contents ($file, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

echo "Thank you for completing this form, we will reply soon";
}
?>
```

How can I fix this problem sir, I used the exact offline code you gave in the tutorial.

I appreciate your kind gestures here to help starters like us.

Thank you,

Comment: Is file `cardealer.csv` also uploaded to the server and has the file correct file permissions? (Namely write?)

Comment: Use the pre-built function http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php.

Answer (score 0):

this to export excel file based on CSV data and download the file 
if you want to write a file you should consider using `chmod`
like this

```
chmod($folder_path. $file_name. ".".$ext, '775');
```

also in this part

```
 fopen("php://output",w);
```

you can change it to

```
fopen($path_to_file,w);
```

you can change the MIME-TYPE and the file extension to what ever you want.

```
/**
*the $array  the data to be converted to CSV
*
*/
    function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename = "export.xls", $delimiter=";") {
        header('Content-Type: application/xls');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
        header("Expires: 0");

        // open the "output" stream
        $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        foreach ($array as $line) {
            fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
        }
    }
```